# Is value of vbNewLine platform-dependent?

Tags: vb.net, mono, cross-platform, newline

Is [`vbNewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbnewline(v=vs.110).aspx) constant equivalent to [`vbCrLf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf(v=vs.110).aspx) (`0x0D 0x0A`) or is it equivalent to [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) which is platform-dependent?

vbNewLine definition is not clear enough here: `Represents a newline character for print and display functions`.

In Windows, vbNewLine has 2 characters. It would be best if someone could verify vbNewLine at Mono. :)

*I would prefer vbNewLine before Environment.Newline if they were equivalent because it is handier.*

Comment: @Steve - linked Q/A is irrelevant to this one. It is not addressing vbNewline. Maybe you can consider removal of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *Mono*, you can find the *Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants* source code [here](https://github.com/mono/mono-basic/blob/master/vbruntime/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft.VisualBasic/Constants.vb). It explicitly states that `vbNewLine` is equal to `vbCrLf`:

```
Public Const vbNewLine As String = vbCrLf
```

For completeness, the corresponding .NET source code can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Constants.vb,a6f1a0943704ca9a).